# Linux CLI change price (awk or sed?)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have price strings formatted as
    `$25.00`
in various html files. I would like to use the Linux command line (BASH, presumably with awk or sed) to increase each price by a certain dollar amount ($3 in this case).

In short, I need to find $nn.00 and replace it with $(n+3)n.00

Started to put it together but I don't know how to add 3 `sed -r 's/([^$][0-9][0-9][.]00). ????' file.html`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data:

```
$ cat prices_file.html
<p>$25.00</p><p>$78.00</p>
<p>$2.00</p>
<p>$101.00</p>
```

Solution with Perl:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/\$(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf("\$%.2f", $1 + 3)/eg' prices_file.html
```

After:

```
$ cat prices_file.html
<p>$28.00</p><p>$81.00</p>
<p>$5.00</p>
<p>$104.00</p>
```

Above example is one of most common perl use cases with substitution.
It will also backup your original file (in `prices_file.html.bak`) in case you do something unwanted to it.

What is maybe not so common is evaluation modifier (`s///e`) which allows you to execute arbitrary perl code in substitution.
Global modifier (`s///g`) tells perl to replace all occurrences (here in a context of line, if you remove `g` modifier if would only replace first price in 1st line of given sample data).

In `sprintf("\$%.2f", $1 + 3)` replacement, `$1` refers to matched group [`(\d+\.\d+)`].

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I really appreciate the detailed explanation and bonus file backup feature as well.